# Application fails on run in a new release of SpringBoot 3.0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, json-rpc, jsonrpc4j

I'm using jsonrpc4j library to handle my jsonrpc api. After migrating to new release of SpringBoot 3.0.0 it builds, but fails on run with an error of RemoteExporter:

```
ERROR 22396 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/remoting/support/RemoteExporter
```

as jsonrpc4j uses it in it.

The reason seems to me in a version of Spring Context which comes with SpringBoot 3.0.0 dependency. `org.springframework.remoting` package is lack of `.support` package in that version.

Is there any way to avoid the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `org.springframework.remoting`  was removed in Spring 6 (see [Drop RPC-style remoting: Hessian, HTTP Invoker, JMS Invoker, JAX-WS #27422](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27422)).  In Spring 5.3, the subclasses of `RemoteExporter` are marked deprecated (see  [Deprecate remoting technologies support #25379](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25379)), but interestingly enough, `RemoteExporter` itself wasn't marked as such, but it has been removed anyway. You'll need to find a replacement library or ask the developers of jsonrpc4j to provide a version which supports Spring 6/Spring Boot 3.

Comment: Seems so. Already opened an issue, hope devs gonna fix that in a new release. Unfortunately couldn't find any other convinient lib.